# How do tf.exe and tfpt.exe establish connections to a TFS instance based on execution directory?

Tags: command-line, tfs, sdk, workspace

I'm doing some work at the command line using using the TFS object model, and I want to reproduce the workspace-detection bahavior seen in tf.exe and tfpt.exe without introducing artifacts because of my own particular implementation. Currently, my scripts require more information than what tf.exe needs--a significant amount of my parameters are there simply to instantiate the connection.

Specifically, I have to require users to explicitly pass in the server Uri (tfsUriString) and the collection name (tfsCollectionName), but this seems needless and annoying since tf.exe is able to do it.

```
    Uri tfsUri = new Uri(tfsUriString);
    TfsConfigurationServer configurationServer = TfsConfigurationServerFactory.GetConfigurationServer(tfsUri);
    ReadOnlyCollection<CatalogNode> collectionNodes = configurationServer.CatalogNode.QueryChildren( new[] { CatalogResourceTypes.ProjectCollection }, false, CatalogQueryOptions.None);
    CatalogNode collectionNode = collectionNodes.Where(node => node.Resource.DisplayName == tfsCollectionName).SingleOrDefault();
    Guid collectionId = new Guid(collectionNode.Resource.Properties["InstanceId"]);
    TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection = configurationServer.GetTeamProjectCollection(collectionId);
    var vcServer = teamProjectCollection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
```

What classes and methods can be used to perform this detection in the same way that tf.exe does?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Team Foundation Server clients use a workspace cache that contains all the user's workspaces for each Team Project Collection that they've used from the current machine.  `tf.exe` uses this cache to determine the `TfsTeamProjectCollection` and `Workspace` to use for the paths given on the command line.

You can get the cached `WorkspaceInfo` for a particular local path by using:

```
Workstation.Current.GetLocalWorkspaceInfo(localPath)
```

Or you can get the entire workspace cache by calling:

```
Workstation.Current.GetAllLocalWorkspaceInfo()
```

The `WorkspaceInfo.ServerUri` property will contain the server URI you can use to create a `TfsTeamProjectCollection` with.

Comment: Fantastic! Works like a charm. I'd been looking around inside the WorkspaceInfo class in hopes of finding some way for it to instantiate itself; never thought of Workstation. Thanks!